# Lambda expression as ThreadStart strange behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - The foreach identifier and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-sharp-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures)
>   [From Eric Lippert’s blog: “don’t close over the loop variable”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190578/from-eric-lipperts-blog-dont-close-over-the-loop-variable)

I'm using a lambda expression as `ThreadStart` parameter, to run a method in a new thread using [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.90).aspx) class. This is my code:

```
delegate void del();

static void Do(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

static del CreateLoop(del Do)
{
    return () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Do();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 0;
    var loop = CreateLoop(() => Do(n));
    new Thread(() => loop()).Start();
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    n = 1;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
0
1
1
1
...
```

How is it possible? 
Why if I change the value of my integer variable `n`, also changes the value of `i` (`Do`'s parameter)?

Comment: @L.B that is about variable scope, not about captured variable...

Comment: gliderkite, so you hit a very special case noone faced before? Read the references again.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a different variable out of it, thus not changing the original value.

After all, all you're really doing is calling that same old 'function', the lambda expression passing the variable i over and over again, which indeed changes. It's nog like you're storing the initial value of the var i somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loop = CreateLoop(() => Do(n));
```

This line is simply creating a new function and assigning it to a variable. This function, among other things, passes the value `n` to the `Do` function. But it's not calling the `Do` function, it's just creating a function which will, when executed, call the `Do` function.

You then start a new thread which calls the function, etc, but your new thread is still executing `Do(n)`, passing the `n` variable to `Do`. That part doesn't change - you've created a function which references a particular place in memory (represented by the variable `n`) and continues to reference that place in memory even as you change the value which is stored there.

I believe the following would "fix" your code:

```
var loop = (int x) => () => CreateLoop(() => Do(x));
new Thread(loop(n)).Start();
```

This passes the value of `n` to the function represented by `loop`, but the `loop` function creates a new place in memory (represented by `x`) in which to store the value. This new place in memory is not affected by subsequent changes to `n`. That is to say, the function you've created does not directly reference the place in memory to which `n` is a pointer.